# Three.js PLYLoader to save geometry to object (async issue)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, three.js

I have an object in which I want to store the geometry contained on a Ply file, for which I have the following:

```
function MyObject(filename) {
  var container = this.createObject(filename);
  this.mesh = container.children[0];
  this.geometry = this.mesh.geometry;
};

MyObject.prototype.createObject = function(filename) {
  var loader = THREE.PLYLoader();
  var container = new THREE.Object3D();
  loader.load(filename, function ( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x0055ff } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.y = -0.25;
    mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.04 );
    container.add( mesh );
  });
  return container;
};
```

But the loader is run asynchronously and therefore when creating `this.mesh` it becomes "undefined" making the program fail at `this.geometry`.

I thought the return function would fix this but it does not and after reading about asynchronicity in javascript I haven't found the solution. Does anyone know how to implement three.js loaders with objects?

Comment: Why not putting the lines
  .mesh = container.children[0];
  .geometry = this.mesh.geometry;
in the body of the function passed to loader.load?
you have to pass "this" and "container" to the createObject function

Comment: Thanks, but I also tried. I'm having the same problems with any method of Three.js that returns an object, like getObjectByName, so maybe I'm not understanding how I'm supposed to use this functions.

Comment: The ideal situation would be that there is a command that stops the flow of execution of javascript and wait for the load to finish. However, I am not very optimistic about that. Otherwise you will have to rethink your desing. Do not access the object returned by your constructor before the load has finished. You may use a flag with default value=false and set it to true in the loader. Then periodically check the flag's value.

Comment: I tried that, but it would crash the browser, I don't think javascript is meant for that. I finally solved it by checking for the object before animating, with and `if`. That way it only starts animating and rendering when the object is loaded.